# How to add numbers of rows and column of matrix in array or list

Tags: java, arrays

I have  given n number of row and column of matrix. and then i want to store that into an array or list whaich i can retrive over for loop later. Here is my code. Here I'm not able to store in to the list.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

                System.out.println("Enter The Number");
                 int n = scan.nextInt();
                 List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                 for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
                     System.out.println("Enter The Number Of Matrix Rows");

                        int matrixRow = scan.nextInt();

                        System.out.println("Enter The Number Of Matrix Columns");

                        int matrixCol = scan.nextInt();

                        int[][] matrix = new int[matrixRow][matrixCol];
                        list.add(matrix);
                 }

          }
```

Any help how i can store and retrieve over for loop.

Comment: You declare a 2D `int[][]` array, but then you never populate it.  Is this the behavior you want your code to have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will not compile due to the type of `list` is not match to the array

Change

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

to

```
List<int[][]> list = new ArrayList<int[][]>();
```

Comment: thanks, it is working. I will see how to use this for `for` or looping retrival.

Comment: @孙兴斌 Sorry I am using `jdk6`